# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource between vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hello I make a GET request to Laravel backend from Vuejs by using axios. 
Laravel api returns blogs. It's okay when there are 4 blogs and over 4 blogs, the error becomes and no data is sent. The Errors' screenshot is 
[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvADO.png)

Here is my JS code

```
    axios.get(url)
    .then((response)=>{
      payload.context.rootState.Misc.pre_loading=false;
      callback(response.data);
    }).catch(error => {


      alert("Server error");
      console.log(error)
  });
```

Here is my Laravel's Kernel

```
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

Here is my cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

Please help me. I don't know what is wrong.

[Here is the screenshot for headers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot7fS.png)
[Data are shown in this preview tag of network.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBH1p.png)

[header's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX9X8.png)
[the response data in the network tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqGij.png)

Comment: In screenshot at the bottom left U use addres http://localhost:8000 but on adress bar you use http://localhost:8080 - so vue is separate project than laravel on diffrent port? Show headers of your GET (chrome>console>networks>your request)

Comment: I have added scrrenshots for you to my post.

Comment: Give screenshots with headers for request that fail

Comment: I have already added screenshots to my post .

Comment: I see only 3 screenshots - first at the top (without headers) and two at the bottom (with success request). But I wanna see headers of request which fail

Comment: I have added a screenshot sir

Comment: You give 2 new screnshots. First is allmost good - but the problem is that you cut-off REQUEST headers at the bottom in that screenshot (but the RESPONSE headers are visible). But I need to see full REQUEST headers. I also notice that in fail request you add `parameter: ?photographer_slug=u_sai` - it is possible that your serwer return 403 for that parameter (maybe you logged user has no right to use `u_sai` value ?) Show code of your server which handle this parameter. Add info about GET and OPTIONS requests (especially headers) for fail and success scenario